# Table view footer disappearing when removing cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiview, tablefooterview

I have a table view with a few sections and in these sections I have a footer views. The thing is when I remove cells from one of the sections for some reason the footer in that section disappears. It returns as soon as I scroll the table view.

I have tried implementing `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`. This brings the footer view back with an animation from the top of the screen. I have then tried turning animations off with `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` to prevent this but the problem stil persists. I simply want the footer view to move up with the rest of the sections and header views without disappearing.

Comment: after `endUpdates()` just `reload tableview`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting footer by code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {

     switch (section) {
    case 4: return "Footer" }
     default: ""
    }
    return title
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> Objective - C:

```
[tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull]];
```